# google-maps-react not working

Tags: google-maps, reactjs, google-maps-react

I'm using react with es2015 javascript and when I use the google-maps-react package I've got the following exception in my console:

> warning.js:36 Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package
>   is deprecated. Use the prop-types package from npm instead.

map.jsx:

```
import React , {Component} from 'react';
import {Map} from 'google-maps-react';

class MapView extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="google-map">
          <Map google={this.props.google} zoom={14} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MapView;
```

Answer (score 1):

As of React **v15.5.0**, propTypes has been moved out of the React module; it now has its own `prop-types` package. Read the blog post https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html

Instead of using `React.PropTypes.whatever`, you have to import it using:

`import PropTypes from 'prop-types';`

(make sure to install it using `npm install --save prop-types`)